# Web Services Authentication

Tags: authentication, web

Suppose we have two web pages residing on two different servers - say Server A and Server B

Now , is there a way , that could help a web page on server A , confirm for sure , that the request that it is getting , is from a specified web page on server B ?

We can't use tokens here , since Session variables would be useless , as the two web pages concerned , are on two different servers.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Simple way, You can send information in url request for webpage on server A which can be hashed at Server B page in some way that can be used on A to ensure that the hashed info is valid and confirms the valid redirection.